# Can't set-up matplotlib's navigation toolbar, Unexpected Type

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, qt-designer

I'm trying to make an app where the matplotlib's tab widget is embedded inside another widget

```
import os

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp
import numpy as np
from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2.QtCore import QTimer
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

from layout import Ui_Form

matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import sys
graphed = False
res = 180

class VentanaPrincipal(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VentanaPrincipal, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ventana = Ui_Form()
        self.ventana.setupUi(self)
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.mainloop)
        self.timer.start(20)
        self.ancho = self.size().height()
        self.alto = self.size().height()
        self.ventana.pshBtnCalcularOrbita.clicked.connect(self.truer)
        self.ventana.pshBtnCalcularOrbita.clicked.connect(self.graph)
        self.oldsize = self.size()
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        self.button = QPushButton('Plot')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.plot)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def truer(self):
        global graphed
        graphed = True

    def graph(self):
        self.ventana.graph()

    def resizeEvent(self,event):
        self.oldsize = event.size()

    def mainloop(self):
        self.ancho = self.size().width()
        self.alto = self.size().height()
        if self.size() != self.oldsize:
            if graphed:
                self.graph()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    aplicacion = VentanaPrincipal()
    aplicacion.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Gives me:

```
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QToolBar(str, parent: QWidget = None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'VentanaPrincipal'
  QToolBar(parent: QWidget = None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'VentanaPrincipal'
```

The Ui_Form is a .py file compiled from the original .ui file from QtDesigner

I've seen an identical example onto another question, the example i grabbed onto was:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QDialog,QApplication,QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
from PySide2 import QtGui
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import random

class Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        # a figure instance to plot on
        self.figure = Figure()
        print(self)
        # this is the Canvas Widget that displays the `figure`
        # it takes the `figure` instance as a parameter to __init__
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)

        # this is the Navigation widget
        # it takes the Canvas widget and a parent
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        print(type(self))
        # Just some button connected to `plot` method
        self.button = QPushButton('Plot')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.plot)

        # set the layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def plot(self):
        ''' plot some random stuff '''
        # random data
        data = [random.random() for i in range(10)]

        # create an axis
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)

        # discards the old graph
        ax.clear()

        # plot data
        ax.plot(data, '*-')

        # refresh canvas
        self.canvas.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = Window()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

There are some prints i put inside the code to check which kind of object is accepted by the QToolbar **init** line inside Matplotlib's backend

Comment: Try moving all PySide imports *before* matplotlib

Comment: It worked ! I would like to know why this worked, didn't know that imports order matter, is it matplotlib using a wrong backend ? I could never have come up with this solution by myself.

Comment: If no backend is already imported and both PyQt and PySide are available, matplotlib defaults to PyQt importing its submodules. While they are both python bindings to Qt, they cannot be used together. If you import PySide *before*, that binding is found in the imported modules and then matplotlib will use it.

Comment: Btw, while generally the import order doesn't matter, it's not *always* true. Even if the rule of thumb is that each module should be self-contained, this cannot physically be possible for modules relying on *other* modules (it wouldn't make any sense to embed Qt in matplotlib), and then they just attempt to find smart ways to accomodate users. In any case, I couldn't find the original reference in the docs, but in the [example](//matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt_sgskip.html) they do specify that you either set the environment variable or import the binding before.